# How to show Android searchview hint as marquee?

Tags: android, searchview, marquee

I encounter a problem when use marquee in android searchview hint.
Marquee is working fine with edittext.
But, I just want to use searview hint with marquee style.
I've looked for possible solutions, but I don't find it out.
Help me pls...

Comment: Hello as far as i know! there is no way to achieve this with default searchview.

Comment: So, you mean what I want is not available. Right?

Comment: yes exactly. you can achieve this by creating your own customized searchview

Comment: To customize  it is not easy, right? To customize it, I've to edit it's some functions in its default class. Like this?

Comment: yeah its bit difficult but achievable :)